# iOS SpriteKit: applyForce to physics body totally different effect depending on device model

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

A friend and I are prototyping some stuff in SpriteKit.   This is not my friend's first time using it but it is my first time.

We have a simple control of a square.   You can run back and forth on a "ground" node and you can touch a jump button to "jump".

With a given set of numbers for mass, gravity, etc, the following

```
[self.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0, 1500000)];
```

causes a normal looking jump (almost a small bunnyhop) when run on an iPad4 in iPhone mode (app is iPhone only for now), but on my 5S the jump is about 20 to 40 times higher and on a 4S the jump is literally like 100 or 200 times higher.   (the "times higher" are a guesstimate based on visually watching, but the iPad looks normal, the 5S looks like a superman jump, and the 4S looks like superman ate his spinach and his wife put out before he jumped)

The exact same code is running on all devices.   I am not sure where to look or what could be causing this.

Comment: Wow, that is an extremely high number to use with applyForce! Are you sure properties like the node's mass and the scene's gravity are the same each time? Are you using any SKFieldNodes in your scene?

Comment: There are no SKFieldNodes, and the scene gravity, node mass, etc are the same all the time.   There is nothing set to change them. Just a few SKLightNodes, a bunch of "ground piece" SKSpriteNodes, and the "player" SKSpriteNode.  And a camera.   The mass is set to 80.0 and the gravity to -9.8.  If you don't change the mass from the default, which is some small less than 0 decimal number, then yes the force would be huge.  Changing the mass to a large number makes you require a larger force to move it :).   I prefer to work in (relatively) whole numbers so the mass and force are adjusted so.

Comment: Well I'm stumped. Can you post more relevant code? What have you tried to isolate this behavior?

Comment: You are using force incorrectly if you are not applying the force during each step of the simulation. I'm assuming this is the case considering the force is extremely large (unless you set you mass to something very high). You should applyImpulses instead of forces if you are applying it instantaneously. You also may want to look into setting the velocity directly to see if you get the same results.

Comment: @EpicByte - that's a good point but how would that explain the differing results on different devices?

Comment: @sangony It shouldn't really. However because apply force is being used incorrectly and apply force is dependent on the steps of the physics simulation, small differences in the timing of the simulation on the devices could be leading to these differences. Apple docs state: "The acceleration is applied for a single simulation step (one frame)." It could be the small timing differences of the step is leading to large differences because the force is very large. This is all speculation though. I recommend the OP try using impulse or setting the velocity directly to narrow the cause of the issue.

Comment: @EpicByte - makes sense. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Some other quotes from docs related to this : "A force is applied for a length of time based on the amount of simulation time that passes between when you apply the force and when the next frame of the simulation is processed. So, to apply a continuous force to an body, you need to make the appropriate method calls each time a new frame is processed. Forces are usually used for continuous effects"

Comment: The applyForce is not being used incorrectly.  It is being called in each update:  so is being called in each simulation step, as directed.  And it is consistent on a given device.  If it was a matter of timing  etc then it would vary on a given device as it would not always run the same each time.  The difference is between device types, and is consistent on a given device.  I have some ideas I am exploring now and will relate more as I learn more.  We are using the scene editor and not building the scene in code and I think has to do with it since the different devices are different sizes

Comment: @EpicByte The force is not "large" given the other values in the physics.  The Apple Docs state that the actual values are not important, as long as the ratios to each other stay the same.  You can have a mass of 10 and a force of 100 or a mass of 1 and a force of 10 and you will get the same effect if I read the doc correctly. "All values in Sprite Kit are specified using the International System of Units (SI units). The actual forces and mass values are not important so long as your game uses consistent values."

Comment: @chadbag That's why I said "...(unless you set your mass to something very high)..." Regardless, if you are using apply force you should be doing it at each step in the simulation to keep the force applied over a period of time. You haven't provided any code showing where you apply the force so everything in my comments are "speculation." Typically the motion of a jump is over a very short period of time so applyImpulse is often used. However if done correctly applyForce could work as well. You haven't stated if changing your code to applyImpulse or modifying the velocity fixed the problem.

Comment: @chadbag So I can't provide any further assistance until you do so. Try the solution I mentioned, post some code showing where and how you use applyForce and we can go from there.

Comment: @chadbag Just so we are on the same page: "A force is applied for a length of time based on the amount of simulation time that passes between when you apply the force and when the next frame of the simulation is processed. So, to apply a continuous force to an body, you need to make the appropriate method calls each time a new frame is processed. Forces are usually used for continuous effects
An impulse makes an instantaneous change to the body’s velocity that is independent of the amount of simulation time that has passed. Impulses are usually used for immediate changes to a body’s velocity."

Comment: @EpicByte  You are correct.  I must amend my comment from earlier.  I wanted a one time application of force, and did not think that the "frame rate" of simulation frames would be different between devices, changing the effect of that force -- my bad.   My buddy I am doing this with got it straightened out by using Impulse for the "jumping" since that is a one  time application.  If you can make an answer out of it I will accept it!

Comment: My earlier comment about the use of force being correct was based on a misunderstanding of what you were saying about force vs impulse.  I thought you meant using force outside of the update: simulation frame cycle and since I was using it inside that cycle I commented as I did.  My bad.

Comment: @chadbag All good, I'm glad you got it working. I have summarized my comments into an answer. It's a great question for future readers. Good luck with your game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should applyImpulse instead of applyForce if you are applying it instantaneously. Regarding applyForce, Apple docs state

> "The acceleration is applied for a single simulation step (one
>   frame)."

It could be the *very* *small* timing differences of the step is leading to large differences because the force is very large over **just 1 frame**. If you are using applyForce you should be doing it at each step in the simulation to keep the force applied over a period of time. Typically the motion of a jump is over a very short period of time so applyImpulse is often used.

Here is another quote from Apple docs regarding force vs impulse:

> "A force is applied for a length of time based on the amount of
>   simulation time that passes between when you apply the force and when
>   the next frame of the simulation is processed. So, to apply a
>   continuous force to an body, you need to make the appropriate method
>   calls each time a new frame is processed. Forces are usually used for
>   continuous effects An impulse makes an instantaneous change to the
>   body’s velocity that is independent of the amount of simulation time
>   that has passed. Impulses are usually used for immediate changes to a
>   body’s velocity."